# Android way to download and immidiately show data

Tags: android, service, download

Imagine that you have data on the server. You should download some XML, parse it and show in activity without saving this data into database.

Which way of async operations you will use to download data and how you will pass it to activity?

Comment: Are you asking how to code a XML parser and display the results in a activity? This question seems very broad, please try to specify what you actually need help with.  Displaying XML data that you "downloaded" and parsed in an activity contains like 4 questions.

Comment: i suggest using JSON and not XML. it is much easier and cleaner!

Comment: I mean what i should choose to download data in this situation - Service, AsyncTask, Thread or something else

Answer (score 0):

When you download ascii files they are read in to a string (http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device) which can then be parsed (http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html). This method never saves data to external storage. It would only exist in RAM.